# Different date formats on different devices with DateUtils

Tags: android, date, format, formatdatetime

I am using the following code to display the date in different languages:

```
int formatTime[] = {
            DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL,
            DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_MONTH,
            DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE,
            DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_TIME,
            DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_WEEKDAY,
            DateUtils.FORMAT_NO_MIDNIGHT,
            DateUtils.FORMAT_NO_MONTH_DAY,
            DateUtils.FORMAT_NO_NOON,
            DateUtils.FORMAT_NO_YEAR,
            DateUtils.FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE,
            DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE,
            DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR,
            DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME,
            DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_WEEKDAY,
            };
    for (int i = 0; i< formatTime.length; i++){
        Log.d("dateFormat " + i, DateUtils.formatDateTime(MyApplication.getMyApplicationContext(), timestamp, formatTime[i]));
    }
```

The output in catalan is in LGE LG-H440n (5.0.1, API 21) and Nexus 4 (5.1.1 API 22):

```
D/dateFormat 0: 7 març
D/dateFormat 1: 7 març
D/dateFormat 2: 7 març
D/dateFormat 3: 7 març
D/dateFormat 4: 7 març
D/dateFormat 5: 7 març
D/dateFormat 6: març
D/dateFormat 7: 7 març
D/dateFormat 8: 7 març
D/dateFormat 9: 7/3
D/dateFormat 10: 7 març
D/dateFormat 11: 7 març de 2016
D/dateFormat 12: 18:11
D/dateFormat 13: dilluns
```

And output in Nexus 5x (6.0.1, API 23):

```
D/dateFormat 0: 7 de març
D/dateFormat 1: 7 de març
D/dateFormat 2: 7 de març
D/dateFormat 3: 7 de març
D/dateFormat 4: 7 de març
D/dateFormat 5: 7 de març
D/dateFormat 6: març
D/dateFormat 7: 7 de març
D/dateFormat 8: 7 de març
D/dateFormat 9: 7/3
D/dateFormat 10: 7 de març
D/dateFormat 11: 7 de març de 2016
D/dateFormat 12: 18:11
D/dateFormat 13: dilluns
```

something similar happens in the time format with:

```
DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(context, timespan * 1000, true).toString().toLowerCase();
```

and output is "a les 18:32" in Nexus and "a la(es) 18:32" in LG-H440n

I suspect that something similar will happen in other languages.
What is this about?

Comment: I am not astonished. Different Android versions retrieve their text resources from different CLDR-versions of Unicode-consortium. And CLDR has indeed changed Catalan resources to fix some related issues recently. That is one of some major reasons why I have developed [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A) carrying its own text resources to enable a unified i18n-experience.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in this way to get the current date in YYYY-MM-DD format and in US Locale.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String CurrentDate = formatter.format(new Date());
Date current_date = formatter.parse(CurrentDate); //In case need the entire Date value
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @MenoHochschild -- The question was asked to have the Date formatted in different languages. I have given an example to format the date in US Locale.

Comment: No, the question was rather WHY are there different outputs/formats in the same language on different devices (example of OP: Catalan language). And using `SimpleDateFormat` would not change the fact of different output on different devices for the same language because it finally accesses the built-in text resources specific for the current version of Android, see also my comment above addressed to the OP.